# Drawing a template using div and css or Just Table Code

Tags: asp.net, css, layout, html

`SPAM` I want to design a web site interface as it is shown int this example web site which has a centred image.

I think I should use margin to put the body  in the web page. the header and the footer div will be above and under the box.

the last thing is the web page is considered to be resized according to the browsers behaviour. For instance the bigger window the bigger page the slow window the small page. You may check it by resizing the windows size of `SPAM`
how can I do it?

Comment: First off, do not push music on the misfortunate user :-)

Comment: SPAM - multiple questions with multiple links to the same site.

Comment: it is not spam. you will see the achievements are different sir. how can I consider myself as a spam, I am over one year member. please be fair sir.

Comment: see if you can't ask questions without adding multiple urls to external websites, kthx.

Comment: I might have been wrong, and if so I apologize, but the way you posted the same url multiple times in multiple questions looks a bit dodgy. Though I wasn't the first to have marked one of your questions as spam, so probably worth being careful with adding too many links to external sites in your questions (especially repeated links to the same site...). And even if your account has been around for a long time, it might have been taken over by someone else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a lot of related questions on stack overflow, but i happen to have a [link](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-full-page.htm) on hand.